exercise package: turn answers on/off by keyword
I am using the exercise package to generate an exercise booklet for a course. I wonder if there's an easy way to turn answers on/off locally rather than globally. To explain: I want to print answers up to some point, then turn them off, so that when I am distributing the booklet on, say, day N, answers are available up to wherever I am in the course on day N, but not later, then the next week, I move the point after which I am hiding solutions, etc.
In essence, have a \answersoff marker that would make it so that in the example below [edit: MWE-ed], the first answer is shown and the second hidden.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{exercise}
\begin{document}
\begin{Exercise}
My first exercise..
\end{Exercise}
\begin{Answer}
My first answer
\end{Answer}

%\answersoff

\begin{Exercise}
My second exercise..
\end{Exercise}
\begin{Answer}
My second answer
\end{Answer}
\end{document}


Welcome to TeX.SX! Maybe you can play with the answerdelayed option and \shipoutAnswer command. If another package is a valid option, you can take a look at xsim. Anyway, you should provide a complete minimal working example (MWE).

MWE-ed it (sorry, thought it was so trivial to MWE it that I could skip the missing 4 lines). The problem with answerdelayed/\shipoutAnswer is that it throws all answers at once after the \shipoutAnswer statement. I don't want this, I want Q1 A1, Q2 A2, etc. (I have dozens of questions over several chapters).

I don't think you can do that directly with the current exercise package implementation.
Currently the printing of answers is set by the switches \@AnswerOutputtrue and \@AnswerOutputfalse. You can define two aliases
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\answerson}{\@AnswerOutputtrue}
\newcommand{\answersoff}{\@AnswerOutputfalse}
\makeatother

to use them directly.
This works, but relies on the internal package implementation. So it would be preferable to use your own switches
\newif\ifprintanswers
\newcommand{\answerson}{\printanswerstrue}
\newcommand{\answersoff}{\printanswersfalse}

and reimplement the Answer environment to store its content only if \ifprintanswers is true :
\NewEnvironmentCopy{OriginalAnswer}{Answer}
\RenewDocumentEnvironment{Answer}{ O{} +b }
{%
  \ifprintanswers
    \begin{OriginalAnswer}[#1]%
      #2
    \end{OriginalAnswer}%
  \fi%
}
{}

Example (note that you should add \answerson in your preamble, as \ifprintanswers is false by default):
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{exercise}

\newif\ifprintanswers
\newcommand{\answerson}{\printanswerstrue}
\newcommand{\answersoff}{\printanswersfalse}
\answerson

\NewEnvironmentCopy{OriginalAnswer}{Answer}
\RenewDocumentEnvironment{Answer}{ O{} +b }
{%
  \ifprintanswers
    \begin{OriginalAnswer}[#1]%
      #2
    \end{OriginalAnswer}%
  \fi%
}
{}

\begin{document}
\begin{Exercise}
  My first exercise..
\end{Exercise}
\begin{Answer}
  My first answer
\end{Answer}

\answersoff

\begin{Exercise}
  My second exercise..
\end{Exercise}
\begin{Answer}
  My second answer
\end{Answer}

\answerson

\begin{Exercise}
  My third exercise..
\end{Exercise}
\begin{Answer}
  My third answer
\end{Answer}


\end{document}



I run into a problem when running this: my latex install doesn't seem to like \NewEnvironmentCopy. I took a look online and found this https://latex.org/forum/viewtopic.php?t=35597
However, my texlive is more recent that this (I am at TeX Live 2022/Debian), which seems to be sufficient given the answer given on that post. I also tried adding \usepackage{letltxmacro} as someone else suggests there, no luck either.
My guess is your answer works, but I need to somehow update my Tex Live distro. I will give it a shot on my partner's Windows machine, see if MikTex is okay with it.

Ok, not even needing to try under windows: one of my ubuntu server boxes has TeX Live 2023/Debian and your code runs on that. Thanks! (Now I need to figure out how to get a more recent TeX Live on my chromebook.)

@Julien \NewEnvironmentCopy was introduced in 2023. Look at Duplicating Environments for alternatives on older distributions.

Thanks! I found another way around: went to the (debian) testing distrib with pinning and used the testing version just for TeX Live. It seems to be working fine. (I suspect I am unlikely to have any issues with a more recent version of TeX Live, it's not as if it's something the linux distro needs to run.)
